# Get a part of string Python

Tags: python, string, csv, substring, extract

I have two columns of a csv file like

```
a aa
b bbb
c b
d nn
ee e
```

I'd like to get something like this

```
- a
- bb
c b
d nn
e -
```

I tried `col1 not in col2` and it's returning me true or false.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? In particular, what output will be for lines `ab ac`, `abc abd`?

Comment: Can you be more accurate in what you mean by "something like this"?

Comment: @jgritty If string from col1 is in col2, col1 string should be replaced by "-" and col2 string should give the rest of the string, similarly the other way around

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completitude i made a list with tuples, the first component of the tuple may be your first column and same for the second element. What you need is something like the manipulation method for your case:

```
lista = [('a','aa'),('b','bbb'), ('c','b'), ('d','nn'),('ee','e')]

def manipulation(first, second):
    if first in second:
        return ('-', second[1:])
    else:
        return (first, second)

[manipulation(a, b) for a, b in lista]
[('-', 'a'), ('-', 'bb'), ('c', 'b'), ('d', 'nn'), ('ee', 'e')]
```

It is not completed, you need to figure out the last case, the - ee one, but a couple of if would do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. My question is not clear enough. My apologies. There are situations where I might need second[:1]. I'm confused how to integrate both.

Comment: What causes the second situation?  Random chance?